# Can not set "Label" to center

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, row

I've added bootstrap and jquery. And in my **index.php**

```
<div  class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="q1" class="col-sm-12">
            <label id="q3">Ass</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried set center label from **css.css**

```
#q1{    background-color: #ffe6e6;
text-align: center;
}

#q3{  text-align: center}
```

This is final [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HCFl.png). So where is my mistake?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/96qstr0x/  what is wrong

Comment: Bootstrap adds it's own `label` styles, so you might want to use dev tools to inspect what CSS is being applied to the `label` element.

Comment: Try adding  the class text-center to q1

Comment: @Chiller Finally it is working!!

Comment: Cheers ..... !!

Comment: yeah, delete `text-align: center` from `.#q1` & add `text-center` as an additional class like: `<div id="q1" class="col-sm-12 text-center">`